# How to count number of occurrences for all different values in database column and obtain 0 if are there empty result?

Tags: postgresql

I'am newby with postgresSQL. 
I have a table with this structured:

```
city          | type     | quantity | sellout   | sellout_update
"ACIREALE"    | "Man"    |  "3"     |"1100.0"   |"366.6666666666666667"
"ACIREALE"    | "Unisex" |  "3"     | "1405.0"  |"468.3333333333333333"
"ACIREALE"    | "Woman"  |  "9"     | "2480.0"  |"275.5555555555555556"
"ALESSANDRIA" | "Kid"    |  "1"     |"100.0"    |"100.0000000000000000"
"ALESSANDRIA" | "Man"    |  "13"    | "3500.0"  |"269.2307692307692308"
"ALESSANDRIA" | "Unisex" |  "6"     | "1485.0"  |"247.5000000000000000"
"ALESSANDRIA" | "Woman"  |  "29"    | "8085.0"  | "278.7931034482758621"
```

I obtain this result from this query:

```
select lg.city, 
        so.type, 
        SUM(so.sell_out_quantity)  as quantity, 
        SUM(so.estimated_sell_out_value_based_on_srp_euro5) as sellout,
        (SUM(so.estimated_sell_out_value_based_on_srp_euro5)/SUM(so.sell_out_quantity )) as sellout_update 
FROM doors As lg INNER JOIN sellout as so ON lg.code = so.code
GROUP BY lg.city, 
         so.type
```

now, i want obtain this result:

```
city        | N man | N Unisex  | N Woman | N Kid | ...   | sellout
"ACIREALE"    | 3     |  "3"      |   9     | **0**     | ...
"ALESSANDRIA" | 1     |  13       |   6     | 29    | ....
```

For each row I want count the number of occurrences for all different values and transpose them in a specific column. I think that i need to different subquery and join them. For Example:

```
...
INNER JOIN (select lg.city, 
                 COALESCE(COUNT(so.type),0) as c_kid                    
                FROM doors As lg INNER JOIN sellout as so ON lg.code = 
                so.code
                WHERE so.type = 'Kid'                   
                GROUP BY lg.city 
                         ) As count_kid ON lg.city = count_kid.city
...
```

It work. (I don't know if exist the a better way to achieve this result)
As it can be see, i use COALESCE function for obtain a 0 if a value doesn't exist but after several attempts I always get an empty line if it doesn't exist. Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `COUNT(so.type)` will never return null, so `COALESCE(COUNT(so.type),0)` wont work the way you would like.

Comment: You should add `CREATE TABLE` statements together with `INSERT` statements for sample data, or use  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11 or similar.

Comment: `SELECT city, ..., SUM(CASE WHEN type='Man' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS "N man", ... FROM ... GROUP BY city ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FILTER` clause

```
SELECT city,
       sum(quantity::integer) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Man') AS man,
       ...
FROM doors JOIN ...
GROUP BY doors.city, ...;
```